# How do I set up multiple https virtual server blocks with Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

I have tried following several on-line tutorials with no avail.
Here are the files I have:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
# HTTP - redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name codytpatterson.com;

    # Use the Let's Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/codytpatterson.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/codytpatterson.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/mobile.codytpatterson.com:

```
# HTTP - redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mobile.codytpatterson.com;

    # Use the Let's Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mobile.codytpatterson.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mobile.codytpatterson.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Both of these files have symbolic links in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. When I run `sudo nginx -t` I am told that I have duplicate applications attempting to listen to the same port (which I thought would not happen because I only have one server file listed as the default) I feel like there is something I am missing that I don't know. Perhaps it has to do with the proxy? Anybody who is experienced in nginx care to enlighten me? Here is my nginx config file just in case it is also of any use:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Perhaps also there is a better way to do this if I'm just wanting a subdomain for the time being. But eventually I would like to be able to host multiple websites on this server so it would be helpful to know how to do it the way I'm doing it (with separate files) as well as setting up an additional subdomain in a single file if that is the easier way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that your redirects for port 80 are missing the `server_name` config, so they're effectively duplicates. Try adding that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Hey @jlengstorf thank you for the answer! I added the `server_name` config and I was still getting the same result. Additionally, I tried uncommenting the line `# server_name_in_redirect off;` in nginx.conf with the same result. Finally, I tried commenting out the `server_name` config in the https server blocks just in case there were any issues with defining the server name twice. Any other thoughts or ideas?